# Drop down to add input when "Other" is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, simple-form

I have a dropdown in my form that needs to render a new text input when the "Other" is selected. I have tried to do this with the following to no avail:

**Rails View**

```
  <div class ="testinputs"
      <li><%= o.input :name, :as => :select, :collection => [:Anniversary, :Birthday, :Graduation, :Holiday, :'Mothers day', :'Fathers day', :'Valentines day', :Wedding, :other ]%></li>
       <%= o.input :name, :as => :hidden %>
  </div>
```

**jquery**

```
$(function() {
    $("#testinputs").change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if(val == 'other') {
            $('input[name="occasion[name]"]').show();
        } else {
            $('input[name="occasion[name]"]').hide();
        }
    }).change();
});
```

The **HTML** rendered by my form:

```
<div class="testinputs" <li=""><div class="control-group select required"><label class="select required control-label" for="occasion_name"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Name</label><div class="controls"><select class="select required" id="occasion_name" name="occasion[name]"><option value=""></option>
    <option value="Valentines day">Valentines day</option>
    <option value="Wedding">Wedding</option>
    <option value="other">other</option></select></div></div>
        <div class="control-group hidden"><div class="controls"><input class="hidden" id="occasion_name" name="occasion[name]" type="hidden"></div></div>
      </div>
```

Comment: an input field with **type="hidden"** will always remain hidden. Create a normal text field and use property like **display : block or none;** or **visibility:hidden**

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are rendering your input as type="hidden" which means it won't be displayed,e ven when you show it via JS.

Use normal text input, make it hidden via css/js and then show it.